# How to overwrite a folder on the computer using functions in R

Tags: r, directory, overwrite

I am trying to implement a code into my script that will create a new folder on my computer and save plots into it, using:

```
daily <- "D:/Work/R/Daily"
dir.create(daily)
for (d in unique(data.air$yr_day)) {
 mypath <- file.path(daily, paste(name, d, ".png", sep = "" )) 
 png(filename = mypath, width = 963, height = 690) 
 timePlot(subset(data.air, yr_day == d), 
       plot.type = "p",
       y.relation = y.scale,
       pollutant = c("co2.ppm", "o2.permeg", "apo"), 
       date.pad = TRUE,
       pch = c(19,19,19),
       cex = 0.2,
       xlab = paste("Time of day in hours on", d),
       ylab = "CO2, O2, and APO concentrations",
       name.pol = c("CO2 (ppm)", "O2 (per meg)", "APO (per meg)"),
       date.breaks = 24,
       date.format = "%H:%M"
  )
 dev.off()
}
```

However, after the first run, whenever I run the code again, the function does not overwrite the old folders and the plots in it, and instead returns this error:

```
Warning message:
In dir.create(daily) : 'D:\Summer Work with Andrew\R\Daily' already exists
```

So how do I change the code so that it will overwrite the old plots/folder with new ones everytime I run the code again?

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to overwrite the folder everytime. You can just add at the top: `if(!file.exists(daily)) dir.create(daily)`. This will create the `daily` folder only if it doesn't already exist. The plots are automatically overwritten.

Comment: @ytk adding your adjustment got rid of the warning message, however, it didn't seem like the plots are overwritten (I checked the date created and it was the old date)

Comment: Testing if the directory exists is what `dir.create` already do. To not see the warning, use `dir.create(path, showWarnings = FALSE)`. If you want to delete everything in the directory, you can `unlink(dir)`before you call `dir.create(dir)`

Comment: @Ulrik thank you, I have managed to do it

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve this problem, thanks to suggestion from the comments. 
To simplify the work for future usage, I have created a new function that does the job as @Ulrik said in the comment above:

```
make.dir <- function(fp) {
if(!file.exists(fp)) {  # If the folder does not exist, create a new one
make.dir(dirname(fp))
dir.create(fp)
} else {   # If it existed, delete and replace with a new one  
unlink(fp, recursive = TRUE)
dir.create(fp)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this post because I had the same question. I tried Tung Linh's answer but I was getting this warning `In dir.create(fp) : '.' already exists` despite the fact I didn't create the folder in advance.

For that reason, I have changed the code a bit and now:

1. It doesn't give any warning.
2. It notifies if the user has overwritten the folder (in case that you create a folder with the same name).

```
make.dir <- function(fp) {
  
  if(!file.exists(fp)) { 
    # If the folder does not exist, create a new one
    dir.create(fp, recursive = TRUE)
    
  } else {   
    # If it existed, delete and replace with a new one  
    unlink(fp, recursive = TRUE)
    dir.create(fp, recursive=TRUE)
    print("The name of the folder had already existed, you need to know that you have overwritten it.")
  }
}
```